# Why doesn't the image from the external link work in gatsby?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

Excuse me, please, I am just learning. In some gatsby templates I can insert as Image - an image from a URL and in some templates Image don't want to display it.

What does it depend on and how to edit the code to make the url work? (My knowledge about graphql is rather basic)

this is the code for the blog template:

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx } from 'theme-ui'
import { Link, graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image"
import { RiArrowRightLine, RiArrowLeftLine } from "react-icons/ri"

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import SEO from '../components/seo';

const styles = {
  'article blockquote': {
    'background-color': 'cardBg'
  },
  pagination: {
    'a': {
      color: 'muted',
      '&.is-active': {
        color: 'text'
      },
      '&:hover': {
        color: 'text'
      }
    }
  }
}

const Pagination = (props) => (
  <div 
    className="pagination -post"
    sx={styles.pagination}
  >
    <ul>
        {(props.previous && props.previous.frontmatter.template === 'blog-post') && (
          <li>
              <Link to={props.previous.frontmatter.slug} rel="prev">
                <p
                  sx={{
                    color: 'muted'
                  }}
                >
                  <span className="icon -left"><RiArrowLeftLine/></span> Previous</p>
                <span className="page-title">{props.previous.frontmatter.title}</span>
              </Link>
          </li>
        )}
        {(props.next && props.next.frontmatter.template === 'blog-post') && (
          <li>
            <Link to={props.next.frontmatter.slug} rel="next">
              <p
                sx={{
                  color: 'muted'
                }}
              >Next <span className="icon -right"><RiArrowRightLine/></span></p>
              <span className="page-title">{props.next.frontmatter.title}</span>
            </Link>
          </li>
        )}
    </ul>
  </div>
)

const Post = ({ data, pageContext }) => {
  const { markdownRemark } = data // data.markdownRemark holds your post data
  const { frontmatter, html, excerpt } = markdownRemark
  const Image = frontmatter.featuredImage ? frontmatter.featuredImage.childImageSharp.fluid : ""
  const { previous, next } = pageContext

  let props = {
    previous,
    next
  }

  return (
    <Layout className="page">
      <SEO
        title={frontmatter.title}
        description={frontmatter.description ? frontmatter.description : excerpt}
        image={Image}
        article={true}
      />
      <article className="blog-post">
        <header className="featured-banner">
          <section className="article-header">
            <h1>{frontmatter.title}</h1>
            <time>{frontmatter.date}</time>
          </section>
          {Image ? (
            <Img 
              fluid={Image} 
              objectFit="cover"
              objectPosition="50% 50%"
              alt={frontmatter.title + ' - Featured image'}
              className="featured-image"
            />
          ) : ""}
        </header>
        
        <div
          className="blog-post-content"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }}
        />
      </article>
      {(previous || next) && (
        <Pagination {...props} />
      )}
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default Post

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query BlogPostQuery($id: String!) {
    markdownRemark( 
      id: { eq: $id }
    ) {
      id
      html
      excerpt(pruneLength: 148)
      frontmatter {
        date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        slug
        title
        description
        featuredImage {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 1980, maxHeight: 768, quality: 80, srcSetBreakpoints: [350, 700, 1050, 1400]) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluidLimitPresentationSize
            }
            sizes {
              src
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

typical post:

```
---
template: blog-post
title: my title
slug: /plant/bud
date: 2020-05-13 12:37
description: abc
featuredImage: /assets/screen-post-hixmjdah9xhoo-unsplash.jpg (but online image from imgurl png doesnt work)
---


post nr 1
```

edited ///

```
plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/static/assets/`,
        name: `assets`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/content/`,
        name: `content`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        gfm: true,
        plugins: [
          netlifyCmsPaths,
          `gatsby-remark-reading-time`,
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              maxWidth: 1024,
              showCaptions: true,
              linkImagesToOriginal: false,
              tracedSVG: true,
              loading: "lazy",
            },
          },
          `gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe`,
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-prismjs`,
            options: {
              classPrefix: "language-",
              inlineCodeMarker: null,
              aliases: {},
              showLineNumbers: false,
              noInlineHighlight: false,
              // By default the HTML entities <>&'" are escaped.
              // Add additional HTML escapes by providing a mapping
              // of HTML entities and their escape value IE: { '}': '&#123;' }
              escapeEntities: {},
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

In Gatsby, you can insert images from external sources using the standard HTML `<img>` tag with the `src` property:

```
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Alt text" width="500" height="600">
```

If you want to keep the benefits of `gatsby-image` across the external (or online) images, you should need to use some dependencies to achieve lazy loading and other features.

However, to use [`gatsby-image`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image/) you need to allow Gatsby and the inferred GraphQL schema to use their transformers ([`gatsby-transformer-sharp`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-transformer-sharp/) and sharps ([`gatsby-plugin-sharp`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-sharp)) across with the filesystem ([`gatsby-source-filesystem`](http://%22gatsby-source-filesystem%22%20https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/working-with-images/#:%7E:text=gatsby-source-filesystem)) or in other words, Gatsby needs to have access to the images that needs to parse to create a valid queryable GraphQL schema, that will be consumed with the `gatsby-image`.

In addition, you need to specify the folder of your project where those images belong (setting the filesystem):

```
const path = require(`path`)

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: path.join(__dirname, `src`, `images`),
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
  ],
}
```

Once the filesystem is set and the images are processed, a GraphQL node is created, and you are allowed to use the fragments like the one you've provided:

```
featuredImage {
  childImageSharp {
    fluid(maxWidth: 1980, maxHeight: 768, quality: 80, srcSetBreakpoints: [350, 700, 1050, 1400]) {
      ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
      ...GatsbyImageSharpFluidLimitPresentationSize
    }
    sizes {
      src
    }
  }
}
```

Since the external images can't be directly processed by Gatsby, they can't be used with `gatsby-image`. Depending on the source of those images, some plugins allow you to keep using `gatsby-image` from external sources (usually from CMSs like [Contentful](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-contentful/?=gatsby-source-contentful#download-assets-for-static-distribution) and others).

You can check for further documentation in [Working with images docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/working-with-images/).

### Update (01/06/2021)

In the last [Gatsby version (v2.30)](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/v2.30/) they've added a new experimental feature, still in beta to [support external images in a `<StaticImage>` component](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/v2.30/#support-remote-image-urls-experimental). To enable it, just upgrade to the latest Gatsby version (via `npm` or `yarn`) and add the following flags in your running scripts:

```
GATSBY_EXPERIMENTAL_REMOTE_IMAGES=1 gatsby develop

GATSBY_EXPERIMENTAL_REMOTE_IMAGES=1 gatsby build
```

You can then pass absolute URLs to `StaticImage`:

```
<StaticImage src="https://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Kittin" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it really brightens up a lot. Okay, but in contrast in a different theme there is no plug-in except gatsby-source-filesystem and the external images work 

And in contrast, where I have a problem is everything you write about. This is how it looks partly (my 1st post edidted for You)

Comment: As I said, there are some CMS (Prism, DatoCMS, Contentful, etc) that allows you to use `gatsby-image` with external images. I assume that the theme you are talking about uses prism (`gatsby-remark-prismjs`) that it's a plugin of (`gatsby-transformer-remark`). In this case you are able to use `gatsby-image` because the source allows you to

Comment: I followed your instructions (remote images & fresh gatsby(, but I still have the same error: `error GraphQL Error Field "thumbnail" must not have a selection since type "String"` , My post template looks like this _---
title: So bad
date: "2017-08-03"
thumbnail: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/images/img1.png
description: Test
---_ , but the external images still don't work.

Comment: This issue usually comes from multiples source. From mismatching dependency versions to having an image into a folder with other type of files, or having a bad naming.